# MS Access: Easiest way to implement a "check all" box in a form with a datasheet subform

Tags: ms-access, controls

I have a form whose main purpose is to contain a datasheet subform (the form provides a common visual theme across the pages as well as navigation buttons and sometimes selection criteria for the subform).

One of my subforms has a check box.

The user behavior will be to:

1. Open this form
2. Filter the datasheet according to some specification
3. Do something off-line involving, e.g., the ten visible line items
4. Check the field (yes/no field) on those ten line items to indicate that it's been done

[image: Screenshot]

What I'd like is for the user to be able to check one box that then checks all the visible boxes.

The challenge is that it must only be the visible ones, i.e. dependent on what filters are in place.

I tried to create a checkbox in the main form labeled "Check All" which runs code something like:

```
me.sfrmReport.Control.reported.value = me.chkCheckAll.value
```

But unfortunately, this only checked the active row, not all of them. I know I could run a query on the underlying table, but it would need to replicate the user filters.

In fact, what might be even cooler would be a "Check highlighted" box that checks the highlighted rows only.

But I think "Check all" would be better.

I tried to find this, but my searching skills failed me. I'd have thought this was something somewhat common, but perhaps I'm thinking about this incorrectly. I do note that there's a sum function which automatically sums just the filtered/visible rows in a datasheet, so the notion of interacting with just the visible rows is at least somewhat standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the check all box certainly should not be on a "row". So one would assume that say beside the combo box, you place a check all box. (can't imagine that the button or code would be place on the row(s)).

So, say beside the combo box in your screen shot, you have a button called check all.

The code behind that button would/could be:

```
dim rst     as dao.RecordSet
set rst = me.MySubForm.Form.RecordSetClone
rst.movefirst
do while rst.EOF = false
   rst.edit
   rst!ResultReported = true
   rst.update
   rst.moveNext
loop
me.MySubForm.Form.Refresh
```

So above will operate directly against the sub forms data source (current filtered recordset).

I "think" from your screen shot, the top part of the form (with combo) is the main form, and the sub form you have displayed is the sub form.

So, of course you will have to replace the name of the controls I used above, and also the field name for the check box.

So the format to get that recordset is:

```
me.MySubFormControlName.Form.RecordSetClone
```

and to fire off a refresh of the sub form after the code runs is of course.

```
me.MySubFormControlName.Form.Refresh
```

Note that intel-sense should work and help you. if the code does not compile, then don't try and run it until it compiles.

Comment: The _Refresh_ should normally not be needed.

Comment: True, the refresh is likely not required. If you assign a full sql statement to the sub form, then access for sure does a automatic re-query. But if you just update the reocrdset, then in some cases you do need the refresh. But, it will likely be ok without a refresh. If some dialog form was popped up, then upon return, then you usually do need the refresh. Since we not assigning the sub forms recordset with a full new sql statement, but are modifying the reocrdset (clone) directly, then often a refresh is required.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will implement this in the next few days and provide the check mark then.

Comment: Minor comment: last line should be .form.refresh. It's missing the .form right now (you have it in the later commentary). But otherwise works perfectly. It's the clone bit that I was missing. Extremely helpful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks  - fixed that refresh